# value of string mistake swift

Tags: swift, xcode

which must check string at value and add array member if not. Problem is that swift reports a mistake  "Value if type array string has no member range"
Is it means than *.range(of:* can't be used here?

```
    var coUnter = 1

    var colorString = [[0,0,0], [1,1,1]]


    while coUnter < 50 {
        var randomNum = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Int(coords.count))))

        if (colorString.range(of: rgbs[randomNum]) != nil){



            colorString = colorString +[rgbs[randomNum]]
        coUnter = 1}
        else {
            coUnter ++}
    // = coUnter + 1


         print (colorString)

    }


}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, actually whats your intension?

Comment: question is: how fix problem with mistake in  if (colorString.range(of: rgbs[randomNum]) != nil){

Comment: do you want to check whether the particular value present in colorstring array?

Comment: your colorString has [[Int]] type , not String.

Comment: and it means that I  need to change it?